# How to consume a response from a WCF REST web service with PHP

Tags: php, .net, web-services, rest

I have webservice built in .net that looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "object/{name}")]
    Object GetObject(string name);
}

public class api : IRestService
{
    OSAE.OSAE osae = new OSAE.OSAE("WebService");

    public Object GetObject(string name)
    {
        // lookup object 
        OSAEObject OSAEobj = osae.GetObjectByName(name);
        Object obj = new Object();
        obj.Name = OSAEobj.Name;
        obj.Address = OSAEobj.Address;
        obj.Type = OSAEobj.Type;
        obj.Container = OSAEobj.Container;
        obj.Enabled = OSAEobj.Enabled;
        obj.Description = OSAEobj.Description;

        return obj;
    }
 }
```

This will give a response that looks like this when I just use a browser to call it:

```
<Object xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OSAERest" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Address/>
<Container>SYSTEM</Container>
<Description>Email</Description>
<Enabled>0</Enabled>
<Name>Email</Name>
<Properties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
<Type>EMAIL</Type>
</Object>
```

I need to be able to consume this with PHP.  I have tried using Pest (https://github.com/educoder/pest), but I can't get anything to work.  Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
require_once 'Includes/PestXML.php';
$pest = new PestXML('http://localhost:8732/api');
$things = $pest->get('/object/email');
$names = $things->xpath('//Object/Description');
while(list( , $node) = each($names)) {
    echo $node,"\n";
}
?>
```

How can I properly consume my web service responses with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Change the WebGet declaration to the following:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "object/{name}")]
```

Then you can consume the response in PHP by just calling json_decode($result). (example below)

```
$url = "http://localhost:8732/api/object/wibble";
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$jsonData = json_decode($response);

var_dump($jsonData);
```

If you set the "json_decode" 2nd argument to true you'll get an associative array rather than an object graph.

Comment: Might be easier to use Pest with this. Just Use PestJSON instead of PestXML after you change your API to serve JSON content.